# TestNG: Running all tests in a given path

Tags: java, ant, testng

I am working on a project that uses TestNG and ant.  I would like to be able to run tests and test classes as they are added to the project, without having to create or edit testng.xml files.  I can't find anything that describes how to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<package>` tag in your testng.xml file.

Comment: Of course!! I should have thought of that myself!  Thanks Cedric, and thanks for the great tool!